# Error while running Node.js program on IBM i (previously known as iSeries or AS/400)

Tags: node.js, ibm-midrange

```
IBM i Version : V7R2M0

node installation path: /QOpenSys/QIBM/ProdData/Node/bin

node -v : v0.12.17
```

I've created a simple console.log('hello world') program, while running getting following error

```
$ cd /QOpenSys/QIBM/ProdData/Node/bin

$ node /home/anoop/index.js  

function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) {         
yntaxError: Unexpected token  
ILLEGAL                                                               
 at exports.runInThisContext    
(vm.js:73:16)                                                       
at Module._compile    
(module.js:443:25)                                                           

at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)   
at Module.load (module.js:355:32)      
at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12) 
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)        
at startup (node.js:129:16)                      
at node.js:814:3
```

Answer (score 0):

It is related to CCSID of file. You need to create file with 1208 CCSID or an ASCII codepage. So file is created as follows

$ touch -C 1208 index.js